# Let P a point inside a trapezoid $ABCD$, find $AP \cdot PC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be an isosceles trapezoid with bases $AB=32$ and $CD=18$. Let $P$ be a point inside $ABCD$ such that $\angle PAD=\angle PBA$ and $\angle PDA=\angle PCD$. Moreover the area of $ABP$ is $192$. Find the product of the lenghts of the segments $PA$ and $PC$.

Comment: What is trapezoid?

Comment: two parallel line segments with two lines connecting them to make a closed shape. the two connecting lines aren't necessarily  parallel.

Comment: @John Watson According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid), "a convex quadrilateral with at least one pair of parallel sides is referred to as a trapezoid". Are you perusing MSE to learn basic terminology?

Comment: @Professor Vector: At my country trapezoid is arbitrary convex quadrilateral and trapez is what you call trapezoid. :) So the answer to your question is yes!

Comment: Why did he get up vote? He didn't show any effort.

Comment: @John Watson It's called "trapezoid" only in (North-) American English, and  "trapezium" elsewhere. And there's no consistent policy at MSE for upvotes, "cool" seems to be sufficient for Beavis and Butthead.

Comment: @John Watson You're not alone, another example would be https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapez_(Geometrie)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\angle PAD=\angle PBA$ the line $AD$ is tangent on circumcircle for $ABP$.  Since $\angle PDA=\angle PCD$ the line $AD$ is also tangent on circumcircle for $PCD$. So $P$ is one of the intersection point of mentioned circles. Therefore it is easy to construct $P$ and it is not uniquely determined with base length and it is easy to see that $PA\cdot PC$ is not numerical determined (drawings in Geogebra).

Comment: Sorry.  I follow that such a $P$ may not exist for a given $ABCD$ also that for a given $ABCD$ there may be two $P$s satisfying the conditions of problem.  I am not following why that implies that given the existence of such a $P$ that $PA\cdot PC$ is not determined.  Could you be a little more expicit?

Comment: It was just an instruction how to draw $P$. Then try to draw different configuration and you will see it is not uniquely  determined.